# Error serializing the security token when switching from ADFS STS to a custom STS

Tags: c#, security, identity, wif

I have a web app (named MyWebClient) calling a service (named MyService) over http. MyService accepts an issued token from ADFS and it is working fine. I want to switch from ADFS to MyCustomSTS (using WIF 4.5). I expect that MyWebClient code won't be changed but I get an error.

The code to Ping to MyService as below

```
var token = GetSecurityToken();

var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.Message, false);

var messageSecurity = serviceBinding.Security.Message;

messageSecurity.IssuedTokenType = TokenTypes.Saml11TokenProfile11;

messageSecurity.IssuerAddress = Constants.StsAddressX509;

messageSecurity.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.SymmetricKey;

messageSecurity.IssuerBinding = stsBinding; 

var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://mylocalhost/MyService.svc")); 

factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =
                 X509CertificateValidationMode.None; 

factory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode =
 X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;


 var service = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);

 var result = service.Ping();
```

I have (what looks like) a valid token from the STS.

However, it throws an exception in the call to Ping to MyService, as follows:

```
There was an error serializing the security token. Please see the
 inner exception for more details. Server stack trace: at
 System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityTokenSerializer.WriteTokenCore(XmlWriter
 writer, SecurityToken token) at
 System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter
 writer, MessageVersion messageVersion) at
 System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageHeader.WriteHeader(XmlDictionaryWriter
 writer, MessageVersion messageVersion) at
 System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAppliedMessage.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter
 writer) at ...
```

After searching around internet, I was suggested to change code a bit to add

```
factory.Credentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;
```

and it works fine again.

My question here is why it was working fine with ADFS without "UseIdentityConfiguration"? Is there anyway to fix it on MyCustomSTS but changing client code?

The reason is that I have a lot of client apps like MyWebClient so changing their code would be a problem to me.

Thanks to you for all of your help and replies. I am really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

For such a long time from the day I posted it, AFAI can see, the problem is because the ADFS is using WIF 3.5 and my STS is using 4.5. Set UseIdentityConfiguration to true is the only one solution to solve it.

One of the great references I have read about it is from leastprivilege blog http://leastprivilege.com/2012/07/15/wcf-and-identity-in-net-4-5-overview/